# 'in the development' or 'with the development'

Tags: prepositions

I have the following sentence:

> His main task is to help us **with** / **in** the development of new methods.

Comment: Pretty similar. What is the issue?

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Thanks for your answer. It isjust a short description of an internship task.

Comment: Both are okay. Is there a reason to use *His*? Is the development of new methods the same as developing new methods?

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Thanks Yosef for your comment. Yes, actually I can get rid of "his" here. Thanks for the advice

Comment: "His main task is to assist us in the development of new methods" ...